# How can I delegate a subdomain on Namecheap to Azure DNS?

Tags: azure, dns, namecheap

I have a Namecheap domain, example.com, and I want "*.sub.example.com" domains to use a DNS Zone that's set up on Azure. My understanding is that I just need to set up NS records on Namecheap for the subdomain that point to the Azure DNS servers, like so:

```
NS Record    sub    ns1-06.azure-dns.com.
NS Record    sub    ns2-06.azure-dns.net.
NS Record    sub    ns3-06.azure-dns.org.
NS Record    sub    ns4-06.azure-dns.info.
```

On the Azure DNS zone, I have an `A` record for `@` and a wildcard record:

```
@    A    3600    X.X.X.X
*    A    3600    X.X.X.X
```

The `sub.example.com` domain resolves just fine, however, when I try to lookup `test.sub.example.com` (using `dig test.sub.example.com`), I get no records.

If I specify the Azure nameserver (eg, `dig @ns1-06.azure-dns.com test.sub.example.com`)  the subdomain records resolve just fine.

I also verified the NS record setup on Namecheap using: `dig NS sub.example.com`, and it shows the correct Azure nameservers.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was an error on my part when entering the subdomain NS records in Namecheap. I entered them as "sub.example.com" when I only needed to specify "sub".

Comment: If you do not use names with a trailing dot, it means they are relative to current zone or said differently the current zone will be appended to them, hence your `sub.example.com` was probably considered to be `sub.example.com.example.com.` Note final dot here which makes the name absolute. Which is why a simple `sub` gives indeed `sub.example.com.`. Besides that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, and in general for similar DNS troubleshooting cases, besides asking your provider directly, giving the real names without obfuscation helps.